# JavaScript setHours() and getHours()

Tags: javascript

I was trying to solve the below:

Create a Date object for the current date and time.
Extract the hours.
Reset the Date object an hour ahead.
Display the date Object in an alert.
Click the Run It button to run your code live.

I coded as below:(CODE A)

```
var d = new Date();
var currHour = d.getHours();
var resetHour = d.setHours(currHour + 1);
alert(resetHour);
```

However, I got an alert with some mix of irrelevant numbers.

But the below code gets the correct answer: (CODE B)

```
var now  = new Date();
var nowHours = now.getHours();
now.setHours(nowHours  + 1);
alert(now);
```

I am new to JavaScript and would like to know:

The difference between CODE A and CODE B is that in the latter an extra variable is not declared in the third line. So why doesn't CODE A work?

Comment: `alert(new Date(resetHour));`

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a free "we read the manual for you" service. You have to read the manual yourself, as programmers have been doing for more than half a century. If you don't learn how to read the manual, you'll never make any progress as a programmer. You cannot post a question to Stack Overflow every single time you were too busy to read the manual or didn't digest what it said. In this case, the relevant manual page is at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours.